# Batch rename files using AntRenamer or equivalent

Tags: file-management

I've read through some of the other batch rename threads, but couldn't find an answer to my problem. Also, I'm using AntRenamer (portable) because I'm uncomfortable using the command line.

Basically, I have a million files named similar to this "John-Smith.jpg" but I need them to look like this "Smith_John.jpg" Any insights would be great!

John-Smith.jpg
Smith_John.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Regular expression` mode in the *Actions* tab:

```
Expression: (.+)-(.+)\.jpg
New name  : $2_$1.jpg
```